# AWS SSM port forwarding bind to external interface

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-systems-manager

I have managed to get SSM port forwarding working to an AWS instance using the following from my "jump server".

```
aws ssm start-session --target $INSTANCE_ID \
                       --document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSession \
                       --parameters '{"portNumber":["3389"],"localPortNumber":["33389"]}'
```

However this seems to bind to localhost only i.e. I can remote desktop to localhost:33389.

I am trying to set this up so I remote desktop to the "jump server" on :33389 from an external machine and this gets forwarded to the AWS instance. Is there any way this can be done?

I can't seem to find any documentation on the AWS-StartPortForwardingSession document.

Answer (score 2):

You can now use a new document called `AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost`.  https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/05/aws-systems-manager-support-port-forwarding-remote-hosts-using-session-manager/

Comment: AWS documentation about this new feature is availble here :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-working-with-sessions-start.html

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `AWS-StartPortForwardingSession` only gives access to the target instance which is very limiting.

You can use `AWS-StartSSHSession` together with `ssh -L 3389:other-instance:3389`.

For ease of use check out [aws-ssm-tools](https://github.com/mludvig/aws-ssm-tools/) and its `ssm-ssh` script, installable e.g. with `pip3 install aws-ssm-tools`.

Then you can do:

```
~ $ ssm-ssh [--profile / --region ..] --list
~ $ ssm-ssh ec2-user@{your-instance} -L 3389:other-instance:3389
```

With `ssm-ssh` you don't need to know the *instance id* and don't have to worry about all the necessary *ssh parameters*, simply use it as a normal `ssh`.

Hope that helps :)